# How can you force focus on an element to support ios voice over?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, accessibility

Is there a way to make the ios voice over focus on a specific element following a user interaction?

I have tried a version of the following example in a React codebase, by using the focus method on a select element when an option gets selected, however while this works on a web browser, it doesn't work on the ios device, instead the focus moves to whatever was behind the option selected.

So for instance if the 'Saab' option was selected, I'd like the user to remain on the dropdown but instead they land on a div element that was behind the Saab dropdown list.

Using a screen reader on a browser I can see that the focus method works to keep the user on the dropdown but on the ios device with voice over, the focus jumps to the item behind.

```
    handleChange = (e) => {
  document.getElementById("cars").focus({preventScroll: true});
}

<select id="cars" name="cars" id="cars" onChange = (e) => {this.handleChange(e)}>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This example works on my iphone.  I double tap on the button and the VO focus moves to the input field and announces it.

Comment: I cannot work out what problem you mean from the example. Are you saying you are doing this on an open drop-down and then when it closes the focus indicator remains where it was? Can you create a fiddle with the actual problem so we can help?

Comment: Sorry that was phrased poorly, I meant a fiddle that replicates the problem as I can see the above could read badly!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie sorry for not being clearer, I've tried to add a more closer example and explain better. Essentially I want focus to remain on a dropdown select element after one of the select options is chosen but instead the option is chosen then the focus stays on something behind the chosen option, which could be another element or button.

Comment: @jobe hmmm that works fine for me, are you using a framework or is this vanilla? Same question for the `<select>` itself, is it just vanilla HTML5 `<select>` or from a library? As a final part of the mystery, if you select an option from the `<select>` then the `<select>` should be focused anyway so you should have no need for this, so I am wondering if something is interfering with normal behaviour.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie this is in React, the select is just a HTML5 select in the component. The page is opening in a mobile app and the user is having the issue there with the voice over app taking focus to the element behind, his happens for any option that is above or below the select element dropdown, the item behind gets the focus. On a desktop chrome browser the focus remains on the select element after clicking on an option at the top or bottom of the list.

Comment: Is it a visual glitch? if you ask the screen reader to read the currently selected item or change the item with the up key does it correct itself? Sadly as I can't replicate it helping you debug will be tough, can you create a codepen or a jsfiddle etc. that we can work with and then we can help you solve. p.s. if it **is** a visual glitch there isn't too much to worry about, it does happen occasionally. As for the refocusing workaround, I imagine it isn't working as the element already has focus, but yet again hard to debug without something to play with sadly.

Comment: So there is no visual glitch as such, the option can be selected fine but after it's selected the focus just drops to the element behind it. If you imagine a list of 10 items appears, and if you select items 1 or 2 or 9 or 10, then because they are quite high up or low down, then the items behind them are focused. If the element already has focus (such as the select element here) then why wouldn't it keep the focus rather than losing it. I have read some posts now which say that ios doesn't work with the html focus method.

Comment: any ideas @GrahamRitchie

Comment: I have a similar issue using VoiceOver on MacBook, where instead of focusing on my form element after navigating to the page, it focuses on the first element which is a "skip to main content" shortcut.